# PHP Close Connection Early / Continue Processing

Tags: php, http, connection, fastcgi

Is it possible to close a PHP connection early **after content has been `echo`ed**? Answers to similar questions on SO require buffering output before `echo`ing. By the time my script is run, content has already been output.

My script does a bunch of analytics stuff using the current page request and session data, so I'd rather not compicate things by running a second process.

I've tried using `fastcgi_finish_request`, but I think my shared host has settings which terminate the script after calling the function. The following produces no log file. However when I comment out `fastcgi_finish_request`, it works as expected.

```
echo "Hello World";
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(30);
fastcgi_finish_request();
file_put_contents('log.txt', time());
```

Comment: Essentially you are just looking to run something in the background?  Personally, I wouldn't rely on `fastcgi_finish_request` for code since it is specific to FPM.

Comment: @Devon Yes, I just want to run something in the background. What would you use?

Comment: Something like this would be probably best to execute a second script with exec() with it sent to the background.  That way it would work on any Linux platform.